# How to fix old embeded iframes with WP-CLI search-replace

Tags: regex, wp-cli

I want to change this:

```
<iframe width="850" height="478" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4zH9Zca1vRM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

For this:

```
https://www.youtu.be/4zH9Zca1vRM
```

For every iframe of youtube video in the database. What is the right sentence for do it? I gess something like this:

**step 1**. Replacing first part:

```
wp search-replace '<iframe width="*" height="*" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' 'https://www.youtu.be/'  --regex
```

**step 2**. Replacing last part:

```
wp search-replace '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>' ''  --regex
```

Is it right? I'm not sure about quotes and wildcards.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use something like regex101.com to test this before you run it on a database.

You could start off with something like:

```
wp search-replace '<iframe ((width|height|frameborder)="\d+" |allowfullscreen)+?src="https?:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/embed\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+?)" ((width|height|frameborder)="\d+" |allowfullscreen)+?>\<\/iframe\>' 'https://www.youtu.be/$1' --regex
```

but I'm not 100% sure of that...